# Porque no me ejecuta un evento MySQL?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Estoy tratando de realizar que se ejecute una acción del lado de la base de datos. El evento solo debe de hacer un UPDATE colocando un cero cuando la hora y la fecha sean igual al del sistema.

El código de mi evento es el siguiente

```
CREATE EVENT dar_salida
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE STARTS '2021-02-08 23:08:00'
DO UPDATE registros set estado = 0 
WHERE horasalida = CURTIME() AND fechasalida = CURDATE();
```

Answer (score 1):

Después de probar muchas formas encontré la forma correcta y logre solucionar mi error. El problema estaba muy fácil me hacia falta "setear" un ON a los eventos.

El código que me funciono es el siguiente:

```
DROP EVENT IF EXISTS `dar_salida`;
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = on;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT `dar_salida`
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE STARTS '2021-02-08 21:58:00' 
    ON COMPLETION PRESERVE 
DO BEGIN 
    UPDATE registros set estado = 0 
    WHERE horasalida = CURTIME() AND fechasalida = CURDATE();
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Fuente donde me guie para solucionar: https://riptutorial.com/mysql/example/15082/create-an-event